# Could not read JSON: Conflicting setter definitions for property

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jackson-annotations

When I call the API for the first time, I receive a JSON response without any error.

When I call the API for the second time, I receive:

```
Could not read JSON: Conflicting setter definitions for property "zipCode": com.sfr.cacheaddress.api.model.Address#setZipCode(1 params) vs com.sfr.cacheaddress.api.model.Address#setZipCode(1 params)
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"@class":"com.sfr.cacheaddress.api.model.MetaAddress","address":{"id":"3525622624","streetNumber":5,"streetNumberComplement":"A","streetType":"RUE","streetName":"RUE DES PERRIERES","streetNumberAndName":"5 A RUE DES PERRIERES","zipCode":"35800","city":"ST BRIAC SUR MER","address":"5 A RUE DES PERRIERES,
    35800 ST BRIAC SUR MER","inseeCode":"35256","enabled":false,"codeRivoli":"0611","matriculeVoie":"00676767"},"complementCount":1}"; line: 1, column: 11
]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "zipCode": com.sfr.cacheaddress.api.model.Address#setZipCode(1 params) vs com.sfr.cacheaddress.api.model.Address#setZipCode(1 params)
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"@class":"com.sfr.cacheaddress.api.model.MetaAddress","address":{"id":"3525622624","streetNumber":5,"streetNumberComplement":"A","streetType":"RUE","streetName":"RUE DES PERRIERES","streetNumberAndName":"5 A RUE DES PERRIERES","zipCode":"35800","city":"ST BRIAC SUR MER","address":"5 A RUE DES PERRIERES,
    35800 ST BRIAC SUR MER","inseeCode":"35256","enabled":false,"codeRivoli":"0611","matriculeVoie":"00676767"},"complementCount":1}"; line: 1, column: 11
```

The Get API:

```
@GetMapping("streetNumber")
public MetaAddress getAddressByIdRivoliStreetNumber(String code) {
        return addressService.findByRivoliStreetNumber(code);
}
```

MetaAddress.java:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MetaAddress {
    Address address;
    long complementCount;
}
```

Address.java:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public final class Address implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String zipCode;
    private String city;

    //@JsonIgnore
    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    @JsonSetter
    public void setZipCode(String[] zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode[0];
    }
}
```

During deserializing, the second `setZipCode(String[] zipCode)` is needed (which contains `@JsonSetter`), I tried to add `@JsonIgnore` to first method `public void setZipCode(String zipCode)` but the issue persists.

Precision: Other APIs which use `Adress` class (not `MetaAddres`) work fine. The issue happens just when I call the API that uses `MetaAddress` object

Anyone encountered the same problem please?

Comment: Do you use any kind of caching?

Comment: Yes, addressService.findByRivoliStreetNumber(code); methode uses @Cacheable annotation like : @Cacheable(
            key = "#root.methodName + '_' + #code",
            unless = "#result==null")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to remove the cache. Another better solution is to remove the conflicting setter by removing one of them or removing both as you are already using `@Data` annotation.

If you expect different zipCode formats from the json returned by `addressService.findByRivoliStreetNumber(code)` such as string and array of strings, then you can deal with both formates as different properties.

If you have a special reason to do this, please mention it. Maybe there is a better design handing of this case.

Comment: Actually, I removed the cache option but I should activate it after.

Comment: Actually, I removed the cache option but I should activate it after when I'll find another solution.  Concerning setters methods , I can't remove one of them. I need one (public void setZipCode(String[] zipCode)) during deserialization of a json , and I need the second (public void setZipCode(String zipCode)) for mapping zipCode property .

Comment: You can try to keep the setter which accepts array/list of strings, and replace `private String zipCode;` with `private List<String> zipCodes;` and in the service/repository level retrieve the first zipCode if you would like.